# How to get max,avg in collections dict(list) in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, collections, defaultdict

I have collections.defaultdict(list) created using collections library.

```
bids = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

this inside some for loop iterates and generates the dict (list)

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'BTCUSDTbid': [Decimal('0.6769610531551781143397029809')], 'BNBUSDTbid': [Decimal('0.5522217722637411184331627582'), Decimal('1.656726308813783962889330683'), Decimal('0.3682020692956294414374608785')]})
```

Now i need for all keys, the max value and average value. I searched and couldnt able to get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some dict comprehensions:

```py
maxes = {key: max(arr) for key, arr in bids.items()}
averages = {key: sum(arr)/len(arr) for key, arr in bids.items()}

# Use like this: print(maxes['BTCUSDTbid'], averages['BTCUSDTbid'])
```

Let me know if there's something there that you don't understand

Comment: Got exactly what i need.. Thanks.. Could you provide me something to read at this default dict on how it works..

Comment: How can i keep key name concat with max, like BTCUSDTbid_max in simple manner.. for maxes and averages..

Comment: Defaultdicts are just like regular dicts, except when you look up something that isn't there, it magically materializes a default value rather than raising KeyError. I would check out the official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Comment: Any better way than key+'max'

Comment: I would recommend keeping two separate dictionaries if possible, but if you must merge them, you could do something like `stats = {(key + "_max"): max(arr) for key, arr in bids.items()}` and then `stats.update({(key + "_average"): sum(arr)/len(arr) for key, arr in bids.items()})`